# is there any unitary matrix that has determinant that is not $\pm 1$ or $\pm i$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I understand that the determinant of any unitary matrix is an absolute value of 1.

$|\det(U)|^2 = \overline{\det(U)}\det(U) =\det(U^*)\det(U) = \det(U^* U) = \det(I) = 1$

Is there any unitary matrix that has determinant that is not $\pm 1$ or $\pm i$ ?

For example, is there any unitary matrix such that $\det(U) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} i$...?

I created unitary matrices randomly and computed the determinants but all of them are either $\pm 1$ or $\pm i$

Comment: Pick any $w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_{n-1},z$ on the unit circle with $z\ne\pm1,\pm i$. Then let $U=V\operatorname{diag}(w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_{n-1},z\overline{w_1w_2\cdots w_{n-1}})V^\ast$ where $V$ is any unitary matrix.

Comment: Thank you. This worked great and I was able to create U with $det(U)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} i$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider

\begin{align*}
A=\begin{pmatrix}
e^{i\pi/8}&0\\
0&e^{i\pi/8}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

We have

\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
e^{i\pi/8}&0\\
0&e^{i\pi/8}
\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}
e^{-i\pi/8}&0\\
0&e^{-i\pi/8}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\
0&1
\end{pmatrix},
\end{align*}

so it is indeed unitary. Moreover, $\det(A)=e^{i\pi/4}$.

Answer (score 7):

The [general expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix#2_%C3%97_2_unitary_matrix) of a $2\times 2$ unitary matrix is
$$
{\displaystyle U={\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\-e^{i\varphi }b^{*}&e^{i\varphi }a^{*}\\\end{bmatrix}},\qquad \left|a\right|^{2}+\left|b\right|^{2}=1,}
$$
which depends on 4 real parameters (the phase of $a$, the phase of $b$, the relative magnitude between $a$ and $b$, and the angle $φ$).

The determinant of such a matrix is
$$
{\displaystyle \det(U)=e^{i\varphi }.}
$$

You could for instance let $\varphi=\pi/4$ to get $\det(U)=\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}+\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}i$.

Comment: @TonyK: $a$ and $b$ are complex. A remark added.

Comment: @TonyK: thanks for correcting the typo.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to generate such unitary matrix by generating a $\mathbb{N}^{n \times n}$ matrix randomly, putting all the Eigen vectors together, then running Gram-Schmidt process to make it orthonormal. So I was doing wrong....Thank you. With your formula, I was able to create $\mathbb{N}^{2 \times 2}$ with any angle.

Comment: @eii0000: you are welcome.